# non-blocking httpclient for SCSt

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

During an investigation into Spring Cloud Data Flow, I observed that the SCSt httpclient processor app will process just one message at a time. This leads to low throughput and low CPU utilisation if the response from the endpoint is delayed. For example, a latency of 5 seconds results in a maximum throughput of 12 messages per minute (assuming a single consumer.)

Is it possible to patch or configure the httpclient to act in a non-blocking fashion? Rather than idling, waiting for a response, can the httpclient process the next message(s) in a loop until it receives a callback for the response?

Comment: Please read this article and reformulate your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An async client would risk message loss since the incoming message will be acknowledged before processing is complete.

Increasing the `....consumer.concurrency` will add more threads and increase throughput.

If you are using the Kafka binder, you need at least as many partitions as the concurrency setting.